# How to show that if a polynomial map is surjective then the map between co ordinate rings is injective

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-writing

I have algebraic sets $X$ and $Y$. Given $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $f^*: A[Y] \rightarrow A[X]$, I am trying to show that if $f$ is surjective then $f^*$ is injective.

So far I've got that $f$ is surjective then for every $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$

I wanted to do a proof by contradiction, so my aim was to show $f^*(\phi_1) = f^*(\phi_2)$ only held if $\phi_1 = \phi_2$. So I was going to state that $\phi_1 \neq \phi_2$ and aim to reach a contradiction. But I can not get it clear in my head how to form the proof.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$? Varieties? Schemes? Something else?

Comment: I've edited the question now, but they're algebraic sets.

Comment: $f^*$ goes in the other direction.

Comment: You're right! My bad, changed now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a non-zero function $\phi \in A[Y]$; then there exists $y \in Y$ such that $\phi(y) \neq 0$. Now take $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Then
$$(f^* \phi)(x) = \phi(f(x))=\phi(y) \neq 0.$$
This shows that the kernel of the ring map $f^*\colon A[Y] \to A[X]$ is the zero ideal, that is $f^*$ is injective.